# what's wrong with this code? Can't find the correct location of webbrowser element

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, element

```
private Point GetElementPosition(IHTMLElement current_element)
    {
        int x_add = current_element.offsetWidth;
        int y_add = current_element.offsetHeight;
        int x = current_element.offsetLeft;
        int y = current_element.offsetTop;
        while ((current_element = current_element.parentElement) !=null)
        {
            x+=current_element.offsetLeft;
            y+= current_element.offsetTop;
        }

        y-=(webBrowser.Location.Y);

        return new Point(x+(x_add/2),y-(y_add/2));
    }
```

This method is supposed to calculate the absolute position of an IHTMLElement on the screen, taking into account the location of the webbrowser control. It then returns a Point variable which corresponds to the middle point of the element. What's wrong with it? It seems to target about 50-60 pixels lower.
Edit: I also tried the same thing but with HtmlElement instead of IHTMLElement. Nothing different came out of it. I used the SetCursorPos function to send the mouse cursor to the calculated result but it is always lower than the desired location. What am I not taking into account?

Comment: Your application might have a 50-60px top header which is not being considered as part of the application window and is missed when getting offsetWidth and offsetHeight. You might have to compensate for that in this code.

Comment: I thought y-=(webBrowser.Location.Y) compensates for that. The application works on full screen

Comment: Can you confirm, comment the line and see what results come up.

Comment: It's more than obvious when you look at the screen that the method returns the wrong calculation. The difference in the Y-axis between the correct point and the calculated one is much bigger than the difference between the top of the screen and the webbrowser control. The question is why is this code wrong?

Comment: it might be obvious to you but not here. Maybe a debug with all of the values appearing will make it easy to see which line is giving wrong values. The code looks fine to me

Comment: I don't believe this is gonna help. I already did that before asking but there is no point (to my knowledge) writing down numerous values (>10) in order to compare them with ... what? Could it be a difference between IHTMLElement.offsetTop and HtmlElement.Rectangle.X? I will try that too...

Comment: No need to write all values here. You can just debug the app and see if the actual offsets you are getting are correct or not. Put a breakpoint somehwhere. Some times its not the element in question but the parent element. Debugging will help see how this function should start and end with correct values. You know the expected value already as you have established that it is 50-60pixel gap in calculation. Its just debugging where this gap is coming in at.

Comment: I already did that as I told you before. I also created a log file which contains all element information but I don't know what to do with this information. I have nothing to compare it with. I do know that I have this 50-60 pixels gap but I don't know why... I guess that something has to be subtracted or something has to be omitted from the addition - what?